# How to know when has_many attributes has changed in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a has_many through relation such as vehicle has_many accessories. On the vehicles table accessories is saved as accessories_ids. How can I execute a after_save callback on vehicle object when accessories_ids has changed? 
Also, I tried `saved_change_to_accessories_ids` which does not seem to work.

Comment: What do you mean by it does not seem to work? Please share your code. Also, just to make sure...are you using `saved_change_to_accessories_ids?` (with a question mark)?

Comment: On using that I just get an error message with `NoMethodError (undefined method saved_change_to_accessories_ids? for Booking)`.

Comment: It would be great if you could include the models code as well as purpose what you want to do, that way we can give advice as well as clear explanation to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

One hacky way to solve this is to set instance variable in the before_save.

```
before_save :set_initial_accessories_ids

private

def set_initial_accessories_ids
  @initial_accessories_ids = self.accessories_ids
end
```

Now in your `after_save` callback you can make use of this variable.

```
def your_callback
  if @initial_accessories_ids.present? && @initial_accessories_ids != self.accessories_ids
    # do something
  end
end
```

This might not be the best solution but should work in your case.